# Excel 2010 Win 7

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I give a fuel report to my fleet manager, which includes a table for each employee that pulled fuel from our tanks. At the bottom of each employee table, I have a small summary of how many gallons were used per fuel type, e.g.

```
 B        C         D
```

Gasoline      48      Gals

I use this formula that considers the "fuel" Column in table"", looks up for text in D3, Table36, and adds all values that match in that one table.

SUMIF(Table13[fuel],"="&VLOOKUP($D$3,Table36, 1, FALSE),Table13[gals])
It works like a charm, but is there a way for me to make the formula so that when I apply it to the next table I don't have to change the table number?

Comment: Read the help of `INDIRECT()` - you should be able to build the table name by concatenating the counter to the fixed part.

Comment: If you refer to the same table as in which the formula is,  then you can just delete the table name

Comment: @MátéJuhász I do the same formula three times on the same table indicating all three types of fuel where the looked up value changes depending on the type of fuel, then I do the same with the next employee on a different table. I do this to every employee that pulled out fuel from our tanks, so I must repeat this tedious task over 60 times.

Comment: Then please part some sample data to let us understand your issue.